# Finding norm of a functional

Tags: functional-analysis

If $f(x)=\sum x_k a_k$, where $x=(x_1,...) \in l^p $ and $a=(a_1,...) \in l^q$, then find the norm of $f$.I am new to functional analysis and I shall be very grateful to you if you can help me. Thank you

My attempt: $|f(x)|\leq \sum |x_k||a_k|\leq (\sum |x_k|^p)^\frac1p (\sum |a_k|^q)^\frac1q =||a||_q ||x||_p$ and hence

$||f||_p \leq ||a||_q$, Am i going in the right direction?

Comment: You are on the right path. Do you know when Holder's inequality attains its equality? That may help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use Hoelder's inequality $\sum |x_k||a_k|\leq (\sum |x_k|^p)^{1/p}(\sum |a_k|^q)^{1/q}$.

$\|f\|=sup${$\|fx\|:\|x\|\leq1$}

and if $x\in l^p=>x\in l^{pq}$

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more please?